# Spring + RESTEasy subresource is not injected with the dependencies

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using Spring for IoC and Data JPA support and JAX-RS support is provided by RESTEasy implementation.

I have the following pom.xml dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Database Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Integration with RESTEasy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

appContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.test" />
</beans:beans>
```

I have two resources:

Parent:

```
@Component
@Path("/parent")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ParentResource {

    @Context
    ResourceContext resourceContext;

    @GET
    @Path("sub")
    public ChildResource getSub() {
        return resourceContext.getResource(ChildResource.class);
    }
}
```

Child:

```
@Component
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ChildResource {

    @Autowired
    Repository1 repository1;

}
```

This example is totally working with Jersey implementation and I can get repository from the sub resource, but in RESTEasy implementation it does not work and instead of repository instance there is null.

There is a workaround, like this:

```
        ChildResource resource = resourceContext.getResource(ChildResource.class);
         resource.setRep(repositoryFromParent);
        return resource;
```

But it is ugly and it should not be in that way (also parent should know about all dependencies of the sub resource which is also not good).

**Has anyone encountered the same issue working with subresources using Spring and RESTEasy together?**

Comment: Hi, i've exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Hello, no, I've sticked to the workaround solution that I was describing in the question as there were no any answers and I did not find any other solution apart from what you can see.